# Почему не могу зайти в настройки роутера?

Tags: windows-10

Не могу зайти в настройки роутера в Windows 10, по адресу 192.168.0.1 хотя интернет есть, как проводной и wi-fi. Параллельно стоит второй ноутбук под Linux Mint и там всё нормально.
Когда захожу в ноутбуке под Windows 10, набирая 192.168.0.1 пишет следующее:
Страница не доступна
Сайт 192.168.0.1 не отправил данных
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Искал решение проблем в интернете, в частности были варианты с другими адресами, но результат тот же

Comment: `tracert` для начала посмотрите в линуксе и в винде. И вообще настройки `ip` на обоих машинах. Может винда куда-то не туда лезет за этим адресом.

Comment: *Не могу зайти в настройки роутера в Windows 10, по адресу 192.168.0.1 хотя интернет есть, как проводной и wi-fi.* В т.ч. и на компе, с которого нет доступа к интерфейсу роутера? А там, пардон, на компе какие адрес и шлюз?

Comment: Нигде никакой прокси/VPN точно не включен?

Comment: ничего не подключено